# Regression model interpretation singular (he) or plural (they)?

Tags: regression, interpretation

I'd like to ask how to correctly interpret regression model (the point in this case is more semantic in nature).

Each observation (case) in my model is a person. My DV is score from math test. IVs are pupils' characteristics.  N=200.

When I try to interpret the model, can I use plurals, such as "pupils with DUMMY_IV have score +5 in opposite of pupils without this DUMMY_IV". That does not make sense to me. I think you can just use singulars, such as "This person (with all other IV constant) has +5 with DUMMY_IV in opposite of person without this DUMMY_IV".

Comment: I disagree. Essentially you're averaging over a set of people, and your statements are about sets, not individuals.

Comment: To be honest I find it it actaully quite difficult to understand the advantage of using plural than singular (which could be just my irrelevant habit). But anyway, the sentence about the necessity for all other IVs to be constant is still valid, right?

Comment: I can't see your results to suggest a wording. There's a complicating issue that English is apparently not your first language, so that it's hard to tell from your slightly awkward wording whether your interpretation is defensible. For much more on such wording, see discussion by David Hoaglin starting https://www.stata-journal.com/sj16-1.html (which will become publicly accessible on the publication of _Stata Journal_ 19(1)).

Comment: Thanks for the article tip. As for the singular/plural, I think I may have been influenced by this text: "I train my students to summarize regression fits using descriptive terminology. So, don’t say “if you increase x_1 by 1 with all the other x’s held constant, then E(y) will change by 0.3.” Instead say, “Comparing two people that differ by 1 in x_1 and who are identical in all the other x’s, you’d predict y to differ by 0.3, on average.” It’s a mouthful but it’s good practice, cos that’s what the regression actually says. I’ve pretty much trained myself to talk that way." - by Andrew Gelman

Comment: Thanks for the quotation, but Andrew Gelman's wording makes use of plurals and the idea of averaging, and so I am happy to think such wording entirely in support of my stance here.